# VS Code extension: How to convert workspace folder uri path to filesystem path?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, uri

I have a Visual Studio Code extension I'm writing that uses the workspace folder path (File > Open Folder) to determine the base directory to run shell commands from. I can get the path from `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.path`, but it causes problems when I use it with `fs.readdir()` because it's repeating the drive letter at the beginning.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\c:\Users\Dave\Desktop\ESP Labs'
```

*Notice the extra C:*

I would like to find a way to convert the URI path to a suitable filesystem path that will work with `fs.readdir()`. I tried `url.fileURLToPath()` but it didn't work and actually caused the extension to stop functioning until I commented out the console.debug line where I tried to display the result.

There's also a property called `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri._fspath` This does what I want, but I'm thinking the underscore indicates the property is private and should not be used directly.

So my question is this...

Is there a method to convert uri.path to a filesystem path or should I just forget about it and use uri._fspath?

The code:

```
/*
 *  Copy entire project directory to remote flash file system. 
 */
let syncCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('mpremote.sync', async () => {
    if (!vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders || vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.length != 1) {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Unable to sync. Open a folder first.')
    }
    else {
        console.debug('vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0]', vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0])
        console.debug('uri._fsPath:', vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri._fsPath)
        //console.debug('url.fileURLToPath:', url.fileURLToPath(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.path))
        let projectRoot = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri._fsPath
        console.debug('Project folder path:', projectRoot)
        let port = await getDevicePort()
        term.sendText(`cd '${projectRoot}'`)
        fs.readdir(projectRoot, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, entries) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Unable to read directory.')
            }
            else {
                console.debug('Directory entries found:', entries.length)
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    console.debug('Examining directory entry:', entry)
                    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                        if (SYNC_IGNORE.includes(entry.name)) {
                            console.debug('Skipping directory:', entry.name)
                        }
                        else {
                            term.sendText(`${PYTHON_BIN} -m mpremote connect ${port} fs cp -r ${entry.name} :`)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        term.sendText(`${PYTHON_BIN} -m mpremote connect ${port} fs cp ${entry.name} :`)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }   
})
```

Debug output showing available uri properties:

```
vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0] {uri: v, name: 'ESP Labs', index: 0}
vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0] {
  uri: v {
    scheme: 'file',
    authority: '',
    path: '/c:/Users/Dave/Desktop/ESP Labs',
    query: '',
    fragment: '',
    _formatted: 'file:///c%3A/Users/Dave/Desktop/ESP%20Labs',
    _fsPath: 'c:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\ESP Labs'
  },
  name: 'ESP Labs',
  index: 0
}
uri._fsPath: c:\Users\Dave\Desktop\ESP Labs
Project folder path: c:\Users\Dave\Desktop\ESP Labs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a
`vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath` property you could use - note no underscore.   It returns the same thing as the `_fsPath` property.

See [vscode api docs: Uri](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri).

[image: uri.fsPath property]

Comment: That worked. Though I'm wondering why it didn't show up in the debug output when I showed `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0])`. Only _fsPath was there. (With the underscore)

Comment: They are both there for me, under `uri`.  `fsPath` is a little further down the list of properties.  If it is missing for you (and not just a scroll problem) you should file an issue.